# VLOOKUP not finding value unless I extend table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a `VLOOKUP` in an excel spreadsheet.

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,'Building blocks'!B7:ZL35, 44)
```

Currently it returns `0`, even though there is text in the corresponding cell. The corresponding cell is only on the 23rd row, and consequently is in the `[table] B7:ZL35`.

Just by tinkering, I have realised that if I change the table up or down, i.e. to `B7:ZL34` or `B7:ZL36`, the `VLOOKUP` suddenly starts working.

This happens with all of the `VLOOKUP`s in my spreadsheet.

Does anyone know why this might be? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, when building a `VLOOKUP` function, you should always make the range for lookup be an absolute reference, otherwise it will shift to other ranges as you copy the formula down. Something like this will probably fix your problem:

`=VLOOKUP(D2,'Building blocks'!$B$7:$ZL$35, 44, FALSE)`